# I wanna fetch all users who have most sparks in last 7 days in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timestamp

I wanna fetch all users who has most sparks in last 7 days
Sparks are something like friends

can anyone help in this problem
Thanks in advance

```
//create schema for users
const UserSchema = new Schema({

  password: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  account_type: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  account_name: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  sparks: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "users",
      },
      status: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        enum: STATUS,
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    },
  ],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

This is my schema

```
router.get("/leaderboard/get/sparks", async (req, res) => {
  let newDate = moment().subtract(7, "day");
  console.log(
    Date("2020-06-26T12:49:29.324Z") < Date("2020-06-24T12:49:29.563+00:00")
  );
  let topUsers = await User.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        "sparks.createdAt": { $eq: new Date("2020-06-24T12:49:29.563+00:00") },
      },
    },
  ]);
  res.status(200).json({ date: topUsers });
});
```

This is what I tried but did not work for me

I tried so many ways but faild
I was searching but not found anthing useful for my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following aggreagtion

```
User.aggregate([
  {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 1, 
      'numberOfSparks': {
        '$cond': {
          'if': {
            '$isArray': '$sparks'
          }, 
          'then': {
            '$size': '$sparks'
          }, 
          'else': 'NA'
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      'numberOfSparks': -1 //sort in descending order
    }
  }, {
    '$limit': 10 // get top 10 users
  }
])
```

Now this will work fine but if this aggregation is used frequently I would advice you a different approach. Aggregation is quite compute intensive it has to check all the users, then generate all the computed field, numberOfSparks, then sort. So as the number of users and sparks grow it could slow your server down.

Instead you could make a `sparkCount` field in your user schema. Then every time a spark is pushed to your User, you could increment a `sparkCount` field. Simply index the `sparkCount` field. Now you can easily query users with top `sparkCount` with a single query;

`User.find({}).sort({sparkCount:-1}).limit(10)`

This query will only read the 10 user documents with top `sparkCount`. No additional computation. And its also very scalable. Number of users and sparks will not effect performance.

Hope it helped

Comment: Hey Thank you so much but I think the last 7 days part is missing in your solution